# Some of url are redirected to https

Tags: redirect, https, magento1.9.2.4

I have install ssl on my site , Everything  works fine on https but I want to use secure urls only for checkout and registration area pages.

For that I have set base url to `http://mydomain` and **Use Secure URLs in Frontend** to `Yes`.

But Some of my urls (category pages) are still redirected to https (after giving 302 Moved Temporarily). And same with all ajax requests through out the site.

I checked `.htaccess` file and found no rule to redirect for those particular urls or any other url.

I also checked my server configuration for redirect of urls but there  also no rules were applied. I also replace my `.htaccess` file default `.htaccess` but it makes no difference.

Does anyone have idea what could be the cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Use these commands to enable the modules.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

2) Check if your SSL is configured correctly on the file **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** like that.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    <path to your crt file>
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   <path to your private key file>

    # Rest of your site config
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

3) So you can use that on yours **.htaccess** file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

4) Run this command to restart your Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: its redirecting all urls to https.

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache

Comment: yes it is enabled